# Shell: вычисление оперативной памяти

Tags: bash, shell

Как вычислить объём оперативной памяти в мегабайтах, поделить память на половину и записать получившееся в переменную?

Долго бился, так и не осилил. Знаю, что это всё делается в одну строку, но объясните, как?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как вычислить объём оперативной памяти

1. `MEM=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{print $2}')`
2. `MEM=$(free | awk 'NR==2{print $2}')`
3. `MEM=$(cat /proc/meminfo | awk 'NR==1{print $2}')`
4. ...

> в мегабайтах, поделить память на половину и записать получившееся в переменную?

Справочник по `bash`, раздел "арифметические операции". Что-то конкретное там непонятно?